# Как добавить папки wwwroot в nuget пакет?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

Пишу сервер на ASP.NET MVC с `<OutputType>library</OutputType>`, затем пакую в `nuget` пакет и использую этот пакет в другом проекте. Проблема в том, что статические файлы в `wwwroot` не добавляются в nuget `пакет`.
Каким образом можно "засунуть" файлы в nuget пакет?
Пытался использовать [это](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4704#issuecomment-288799238).
В других проектах, где надо было включить dll-файл это помогло, но тут нет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751019/packing-static-content-in-nuget-for-packagereferece-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально я пытался использовать вот это:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\**\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"></Content>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Весь нужные мне файлы добавлялись в `.nuspec` в виде

```
<contentFiles>
    <files inlude="any/any/fileName" buildAction="Content" />
</contentFiles>
```

Но при сборке они не копировались в сборку. Мне помогла вставка `PackageCopyToOutput="true"`, она как раз добавляет в файле `.nuspec` `copyToOutput="true"` для каждого файла
Рабочий код выглядит вот так:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\**\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" PackageCopyToOutput="true" ></Content>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="path/to/folder" />
</ItemGroup>
```

или

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="path/to/folder/**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Что-то из этого должно сработать, у меня на проекте так файлы в билд подкладываются.